# Render bug in new react project

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to render this in a new react project but nothing render do you guys have an idea?

Link (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJdxZJ?editors=1101)

code :

```
class App extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
  <div>
    <div className="content" id='one' alt=''/>
    <div className="content" id='two' alt=''/>
    <div className="content" id='three' alt=''/>
    <div className="content" id='four' alt=''/>
    <div className="content" id='five' alt=''/>
  </div>
);
}}

export default App;
```

css

same as the link

Comment: The codepen code snippet is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your CSS is not included in the HTML. Either you have to do an import of your CSS so that Webpack picks up. Or you should include the final CSS in index.html.

Comment: I imported it with   : import "./App.css"